# Share App Engine Calendar with secondary domain using API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I have a Google calendar that is associated with an App Engine instance. I want to share this calendar with a **secondary domain** e.g. 'myotherdomain.com'. Is this possible? If so how?

I am trying to do this with Google's python client library for the [calendar API v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert)
Here is what I am trying:

```
rule = {
'scope': {
    'type': 'domain',
    'value': 'myotherdomain.com',
},
'role': 'reader'
}

created_rule = service.acl().insert(calendarId='calendarID', body=rule).execute()
```

When I try this I get the following error:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting ... returned "Invalid scope value.">
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible?

Comment: I"m having the exact same problem. Did you ever find a solution? It seems like value: 'myotherdomain.com' would be the correct syntax, but apparently not.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. I'm afraid this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You cannot share a calendar with a secondary domain.